# Different typeof result on the same object

Tags: javascript, typeof

I am getting some data from S3 using AWS SDK. The response I am getting is this:

```
{
...
,
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "data copy.csv",
            "LastModified": "2021-02-19T11:16:24.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"69d6972deead4b9a378473654c878d75\"",
            "Size": 305,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        },
        {
            "Key": "data.csv",
            "LastModified": "2021-02-19T11:16:24.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"69d6972deead4b9a378473654c878d75\"",
            "Size": 305,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        },
        {
            "Key": "folder1/",
            "LastModified": "2021-02-19T11:16:12.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"",
            "Size": 0,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        },
        {
            "Key": "folder2/",
            "LastModified": "2021-02-19T11:16:16.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"",
            "Size": 0,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        }
    ],
...
}
```

When I loop through the properties of one of the Contents items using this code, I can see that type of each of the items is "string":

```
for (const property in Contents[0]) {
   console.log(`Type of ${property}: ${typeof property}`);
}
```

outputs:

```
Type of Key: string
Type of LastModified: string
Type of ETag: string
Type of Size: string
Type of StorageClass: string
```

I want to sort the items by their date - "LastModified". The problem is that when I ask for the type of "LastModified", the output is "object".

```
console.log(typeof Contents[0].LastModified); // object
console.log(typeof Contents[0]['LastModified']); // object
```

Since it's an object, I cannot compare using String comparison. So my questions are:

1. Why does one method say it's a "string" and another one says it's an "object"?
2. What is the best way to convert it to a string (or a date) so I can compare the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

```
for (const property in Contents[0]) {
   console.log(`Type of ${property}: ${typeof property}`);
}
```

The property *key* is a string.  You're testing typeof of the property key, not the property value.

Typeof the property value would be

```
for (const property in Contents[0]) {
   console.log(`Type of ${property}: ${typeof Contents[0][property]}`);
}
```

2. It most likely has already been converted to a native Date object by the AWS SDK.  For comparison, use `Contents[0].LastModified.getTime()` to return the UNIX epoch timestamp (in milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

> Note that if your dates are in string format, you first need to parse them to Date

**sort an object array by date property?**

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
// Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
// to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

For your code array will be replaced with `Contents[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Each item in `Contents` array is an object of key-value pairs. First method you check `typeof` the “key” (the `property` in your code), while second method you check against the “value”. No wonder they say different things.

AWS SDK deserializes/revives those content items into native JS object. It turn the string representation of date into a JS `Date` instance, that why `typeof` check says "object". If you check `instanceof Contents[0].LastModified === Date` it will say `true`.

To sort items by date, best practice is to convert date value into number, value of which is integer that represents unix timestamp in milliseconds. Example:

```js
Contents.sort((a, b) => Number(a.LastModified) - Number(b.LastModified))
```